# May I use OpenCV in a customized FFMPEG filter?

Tags: opencv, video, ffmpeg

I am new to FFMPEG and OpenCV. I hope to overlay a heatmap video on top of a video. There could be two solutions:
(1) Make a customized FFMPEG filter. When looping over each frame, calculate the heatmap for that frame and overlay it with the video frame. Here, I need some matrix operations to calculate the heatmap. May I use OpenCV for these operations inside the FFMPEG filter?
(2) Generate the heatmap, using OpenCV, as a video and then use FFMPEG to overly the heatmap video on top of the original video.

Looks like the first one fits the FFMPEG workflow, but I am still not sure which solution is better, or if there are better solutions. Especially, I am not sure if I can use OpenCV inside FFMPEG.

Thanks.

Comment: using just opencv should be enough. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/wlitwin/heatmap).

Comment: Thanks, IncBrain. The example is nice but may not meet my need completely.

Comment: (Continue) Because: I do not need to play with the overly result in realtime. I have to save it somewhere as a video.

Comment: (Continue) According to http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-write/video-write.html "OpenCV is mainly a computer vision library, not a video stream, codec and write one. Therefore, the developers tried to keep this part as simple as possible. Due to this OpenCV for video containers supports only the avi extension, its first version. A direct limitation of this is that you cannot save a video file larger than 2 GB. Furthermore you can only create and expand a single video track inside the container. No audio or other track editing support here.)

Comment: (Continue) If I use OpenCV to create a heatmap video or a video with overlayed heatmap on top of the video, the size could be much bigger than 2G and there will be no audio.

Comment: So, I am still thinking the FFMPEG filter could be a better solution. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When you run .configure, use --enable-libopencv (it's in the advanced option help menu).  You should then be able to import opencv libs into an ffmpeg filter you write.  (I haven't tried this before, but have done some thing similar using the CUDA SDK, which btw, might be a good option for your linear algebra.)